# Where can I submit improvements in Code for the CMS Joomla?

Tags: joomla, pagination, joomla-template

The Pagination of Joomla doesn't allow to make the link of the current page to be linkable.

In the file: TEMPLATE_LOCATION > html > pagination.php is a function with the following:
pagination_item_inactive()
Input variable $item is an object with fields:
$item->base : integer
$item->link : string
$item->text : string

But $item->link is always empty.
The file: libraries > joomla > html > pagination.php within function _buildDataObject()
Line 521 should be changed from:
    if ($i != $this->get('pages.current') || $this->_viewall)

to
    if (!$this->_viewall)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

How is this an improvement? Why would you link to the page you are already on? I am afraid you will probably be outnumbered in this case. Most people are going to want to leave it alone, particularly since you can use `JURI::current();` to get that URL if you need it anywhere.

In any case, here is a guide to submitting patches.

http://docs.joomla.org/Patch_submission_guidelines